# Prove that simple conditional statement is tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This should be pretty easy, but I don't know how to turn the conditional statement into a tauntology.

The statement is:

$$    (p \land q) \to p$$

I am able to turn it into:

$$   (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \lor p$$

But now what?

Comment: So it is equivalent to $(\lnot p\lor p) \lor \lnot q.$

Comment: @tetori Yes, I know that, but that is not a tautology?

Comment: Ah, danmit, yes it is. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue:

$$\begin{align} (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \lor p &\equiv p \lor (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \\ & \equiv  (p \lor \lnot p) \lor \lnot q \\
& \equiv \top \lor \lnot q \\
&\equiv \top
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I did not consider the OR. Thanks. I'll accept in 11 minutes. Btw, you answered my previous question about logic math. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @amWhy A reason for each step will make your answer more convincing.

Comment: @Hassan I like to leave a little work for the OP! ;-)